# Difference between primitive companion constants and java wrapper constant

Tags: kotlin, constants, primitive

Kotlin redefines a number of primitive constants that are already defined in Java, such as `Long.MAX_VALUE` or `Double.NaN`.

What is the a difference between them and which should be preferred when coding in Kotlin?

To be clear, I'm referring, for example, to:

```
kotlin.Long.Companion.MAX_VALUE
java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general phenomenon: a large part of Kotlin standard library is basically the same as in Java. This is so that

1. Kotlin can provide more precise types: nullable vs non-nullable or `List` vs `MutableList`;
2. This part of the library can be accessed from Kotlin-JS or Kotlin-Native, or other future Kotlin implementations.

For both reasons, stick with the Kotlin standard library types and methods unless you have some specific need to use the Java ones.

`Long` (and `Int`, etc.) are even something of a special case, because they correspond to more than one Java type: in some contexts they end up as the primitive (`long`), in others as its boxed version (`java.lang.Long`). You mostly don't care about this difference in Kotlin, so there's even better reason to keep using `kotlin.Long`.

Answer (score 1):

The Kotlin `Long` class (and all others which have a counterpart in Java) are wrappers, which depending if the type is nullable or not represent the value internally (on the JVM) with `int` (primitive, not nullable) or `Integer` (object, nullable).

Take a look [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/1.2.30/core/builtins/native/kotlin/Primitives.kt#L578):

> Represents a 64-bit signed integer.
>   On the JVM, non-nullable values of this type are represented as values of the primitive type `long`.

Both the Kotlin and the Java version of `MAX_VALUE` are exactly `9223372036854775807L`, but since `kotlin.Long` is a wrapper, its implementation can change which may change `MAX_VALUE`, so it will be better to stick to `kotlin.Long.Companion.MAX_VALUE`.